# the uniform continuity of 1/x

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

It is known that the function

$f(x)=1/x$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$, which can be proven easily by taking $\delta\in(0,1)$ and ended up getting some $\epsilon$ bigger than expect.

It is also known $f(x)=1/x$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty)$.

Now, finally, something I found strange when I close the open left bracket on the left, and replace with some number $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$ i.e.

$f(x)=1/x$ is uniformly continuous on $[\mu,\infty)$.

What is the intuition behind these results and their proofs?

Comment: $\frac{1}{x}$ isn't even defined on $0$... The third statement is meaningless. Might as well ask why $\sqrt x$ isn't uniformly continuous on $(-1,0)$

Comment: To be fair, you could define $g(x) = a\chi_{\{0\}}(x) + \frac1x(1-\chi_{\{0\}})$ for some $a\in\mathbb R$.. But $g$ still wouldn't be continuous at $0$.l

Comment: IF $\mu>0$, then $1/x$ _is_ actually uniformly continuous on $[\mu,\infty)$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes I know, but why $1/x$ not u.c. on $(1,+\infty)$? the intuition?

Comment: @math101: How I think about it is that the _slope_ of $1/x$ is bounded on $[\mu,\infty)$ -- I know the magnitude of the slope decreases monotonically towards zero, so it can never be (absolutely) larger than the finite value it has at $\mu$. Once we know an upper bound for the slope, say, $m$, we can use that upper bound to find a $\delta$ that works for an $\varepsilon$ no matter where on the interval $x$ is. (In fancier words, a function with bounded derivative on an interval is Lipschitz continuous in that interval, and therefore also uniformly continuous).

Comment: @math101: $1/x$ **is** uniformly continuous both on $[1,\infty)$ and on $(1,\infty)$. It's not not whether the bracket is open or closed that makes the difference, but whether the interval you're looking at contains numbers arbitrarily close to $0$ in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way to see the uniform continuity is the mean value theorem
$$
f(x) - f(y) = (x-y) f'(z)
$$
with $x < z < y$

So if you are on interval on which $|f'|$ is bounded by $L$ then
$$
|f(x) - f(y) | \leq L|x-y|
$$
and uniform continuity is immediate.

In this case such an interval is $[\mu,\infty)$